# jQuery multidimensional JSON array with different data in the same JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is slightly difficult to explain but I'll try my best to explain it so I can get some help and hopefully someone sheds some light on this issue.

Basically, I have a JSON that looks like this:

```
    "created_at": "Sun Apr 09 17:56:20 +0000 2017",
    "id": 851131679167139842,
    "id_str": "851131679167139842",
    "text": "hello world with an image goes here as a test! https:\/\/t.co\/jNfdESxPcn",
    "truncated": false,
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [],
        "symbols": [],
        "user_mentions": [],
        "urls": [],
        "media": [{
            "id": 851131665623732225,
            "id_str": "851131665623732225",
            "indices": [47, 70],
            "media_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/C8_TvYqW0AEbBaP.jpg",
            "media_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/C8_TvYqW0AEbBaP.jpg",
            "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/jNfdESxPcn",
            "display_url": "pic.twitter.com\/jNfdESxPcn",
            "expanded_url": "https:\/\/twitter.com\/DavidHoperz\/status\/851131679167139842\/photo\/1",
            "type": "photo",
            "sizes": {
                "thumb": {
                    "w": 150,
                    "h": 150,
                    "resize": "crop"
                },
                "large": {
                    "w": 670,
                    "h": 728,
                    "resize": "fit"
                },
                "small": {
                    "w": 626,
                    "h": 680,
                    "resize": "fit"
                },
                "medium": {
                    "w": 670,
                    "h": 728,
                    "resize": "fit"
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    "extended_entities": {
        "media": [{
            "id": 851131665623732225,
            "id_str": "851131665623732225",
            "indices": [47, 70],
            "media_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/C8_TvYqW0AEbBaP.jpg",
            "media_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/C8_TvYqW0AEbBaP.jpg",
            "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/jNfdESxPcn",
            "display_url": "pic.twitter.com\/jNfdESxPcn",
            "expanded_url": "https:\/\/twitter.com\/DavidHoperz\/status\/851131679167139842\/photo\/1",
            "type": "photo",
            "sizes": {
                "thumb": {
                    "w": 150,
                    "h": 150,
                    "resize": "crop"
                },
                "large": {
                    "w": 670,
                    "h": 728,
                    "resize": "fit"
                },
                "small": {
                    "w": 626,
                    "h": 680,
                    "resize": "fit"
                },
                "medium": {
                    "w": 670,
                    "h": 728,
                    "resize": "fit"
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    "source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e",
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "user": {
        "id": 851119985732800513,
        "id_str": "851119985732800513",
        "name": "David",
        "screen_name": "DavidHoperz",
        "location": "",
        "description": "",
        "url": null,
        "entities": {
            "description": {
                "urls": []
            }
        },
        "protected": false,
        "followers_count": 0,
        "friends_count": 21,
        "listed_count": 0,
        "created_at": "Sun Apr 09 17:09:52 +0000 2017",
        "favourites_count": 0,
        "utc_offset": null,
        "time_zone": null,
        "geo_enabled": false,
        "verified": false,
        "statuses_count": 3,
        "lang": "en",
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "is_translator": false,
        "is_translation_enabled": false,
        "profile_background_color": "F5F8FA",
        "profile_background_image_url": null,
        "profile_background_image_url_https": null,
        "profile_background_tile": false,
        "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/851182210732494848\/lmgbNLvC_normal.jpg",
        "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/851182210732494848\/lmgbNLvC_normal.jpg",
        "profile_link_color": "1DA1F2",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
        "profile_text_color": "333333",
        "profile_use_background_image": true,
        "has_extended_profile": false,
        "default_profile": true,
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "following": false,
        "follow_request_sent": false,
        "notifications": false,
        "translator_type": "none"
    },
    "geo": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "place": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "is_quote_status": false,
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "favorite_count": 0,
    "favorited": false,
    "retweeted": false,
    "possibly_sensitive": false,
    "lang": "en"
}, {
    "created_at": "Sun Apr 09 17:47:36 +0000 2017",
    "id": 851129482832470026,
    "id_str": "851129482832470026",
    "text": "How to display twitter posts using javascript https:\/\/t.co\/I49vjVbAUJ",
    "truncated": false,
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [],
        "symbols": [],
        "user_mentions": [],
        "urls": [{
            "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/I49vjVbAUJ",
            "expanded_url": "https:\/\/www.script-tutorials.com\/how-to-display-twitter-posts-using-javascript\/",
            "display_url": "script-tutorials.com\/how-to-display\u2026",
            "indices": [46, 69]
        }]
    },
    "source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e",
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "user": {
        "id": 851119985732800513,
        "id_str": "851119985732800513",
        "name": "David",
        "screen_name": "DavidHoperz",
        "location": "",
        "description": "",
        "url": null,
        "entities": {
            "description": {
                "urls": []
            }
        },
        "protected": false,
        "followers_count": 0,
        "friends_count": 21,
        "listed_count": 0,
        "created_at": "Sun Apr 09 17:09:52 +0000 2017",
        "favourites_count": 0,
        "utc_offset": null,
        "time_zone": null,
        "geo_enabled": false,
        "verified": false,
        "statuses_count": 3,
        "lang": "en",
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "is_translator": false,
        "is_translation_enabled": false,
        "profile_background_color": "F5F8FA",
        "profile_background_image_url": null,
        "profile_background_image_url_https": null,
        "profile_background_tile": false,
        "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/851182210732494848\/lmgbNLvC_normal.jpg",
        "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/851182210732494848\/lmgbNLvC_normal.jpg",
        "profile_link_color": "1DA1F2",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
        "profile_text_color": "333333",
        "profile_use_background_image": true,
        "has_extended_profile": false,
        "default_profile": true,
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "following": false,
        "follow_request_sent": false,
        "notifications": false,
        "translator_type": "none"
    },
    "geo": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "place": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "is_quote_status": false,
    "retweet_count": 2,
    "favorite_count": 1,
    "favorited": false,
    "retweeted": false,
    "possibly_sensitive": false,
    "lang": "en"
}, {
    "created_at": "Sun Apr 09 17:33:43 +0000 2017",
    "id": 851125986976567297,
    "id_str": "851125986976567297",
    "text": "Hello world",
    "truncated": false,
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [],
        "symbols": [],
        "user_mentions": [],
        "urls": []
    },
    "source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e",
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "user": {
        "id": 851119985732800513,
        "id_str": "851119985732800513",
        "name": "David",
        "screen_name": "DavidHoperz",
        "location": "",
        "description": "",
        "url": null,
        "entities": {
            "description": {
                "urls": []
            }
        },
        "protected": false,
        "followers_count": 0,
        "friends_count": 21,
        "listed_count": 0,
        "created_at": "Sun Apr 09 17:09:52 +0000 2017",
        "favourites_count": 0,
        "utc_offset": null,
        "time_zone": null,
        "geo_enabled": false,
        "verified": false,
        "statuses_count": 3,
        "lang": "en",
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "is_translator": false,
        "is_translation_enabled": false,
        "profile_background_color": "F5F8FA",
        "profile_background_image_url": null,
        "profile_background_image_url_https": null,
        "profile_background_tile": false,
        "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/851182210732494848\/lmgbNLvC_normal.jpg",
        "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/851182210732494848\/lmgbNLvC_normal.jpg",
        "profile_link_color": "1DA1F2",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
        "profile_text_color": "333333",
        "profile_use_background_image": true,
        "has_extended_profile": false,
        "default_profile": true,
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "following": false,
        "follow_request_sent": false,
        "notifications": false,
        "translator_type": "none"
    },
    "geo": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "place": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "is_quote_status": false,
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "favorite_count": 0,
    "favorited": false,
    "retweeted": false,
    "lang": "en"
}]
```

And I have a jQuery to read the JSON data that looks like this:

```
var poutput = $('.listHolder');

$.ajax({
    url: 'page.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function(pi,item){ 
            str = item.id_str;

            var products = '<div id="'+item.id_str+'" class="items">'+
                '<p class="names">'+item.created_at+'</p>'+
                '<p class="names">'+item.text+'</p>'+
                '<img src="'+item.entities.media[0].media_url_https+'" width="100%">'+
                '</div>';
            console.log(products);
            poutput.append(products);
        });
    },
    error: function(){
        //alert('There was an error loading the data.');
    }
});
```

If you look at the JSON data (*first code above*), you will see that some of the data has a `media_url_https` and some Do not have that.

This is causing me an issue because when I try to get all the JSON data with my jQuery code above, it will only get the data that has the `media_url_https` in it and IGNORES the other ones that do not have the `media_url_https`.

But when I remove the `'<img src="'+item.entities.media[0].media_url_https+'" width="100%">'+` from my code, it will get all the data BUT there wont be any images (the images are required too)!

Is there any way to get all the data from that JSON data including images etc etc?

I hope this makes sense and someone can help me resolve this issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

This is How I tried to use if() and else() statements:

```
        $.each(data, function(pi,item){ 
            str = item.id_str;  
            
        var media ="";
        
        var mediaUrl = item.entities.media[0].media_url_https;
        
        if(mediaUrl !=''){
        
        media = '<img src="'+item.entities.media[0].media_url_https+'" width="100%">';
        
        }else{
        media = '';
        
        }

            
            //alert(item.entities.media[0].media_url_https);
               var products = '<div id="'+item.id_str+'" class="items">'+
                               '<p class="names">'+item.text+'</p>'+
                                media+
                               '</div>';


///reset of my code........
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If you want there to always be an image, then there always has to be a `media_url_https` value. What image should be shown if that value doesn't exist?

Comment: You need `if()` conditionals to check properties and react accordingly. Beyond that it isn't clear what expected results are

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Sorry if its a bit confusing. Basically I need all the data (the ones with the images and the ones without images). with my current jQuery code, i can only either get the ones with images or the ones without images.

Comment: @charlietfl, To be honest, I did try the if() statement and that didn't work either. I can update my question with the if statement if required.

Comment: unless you explain what should happen based on property conditions it's hard to help

Comment: @charlietfl, I have updated my code with the `if()` statement. Basically, I need to get all the data from that JSON data but currently, i can only get the ones that that have the `media_url_https` in them.

Comment: any errors thrown in browser console?

Comment: All your items have `item.entities`, but only some have `item.entities.media`, so you should start your conditionals with `if (item.entities.media)`, because checking anything further down the chain will cause an error if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @charlietfl, Yes. the error is: `TypeError: item.entities.media is undefined`. but the data with `media_url_https` still being displayed in the page properly! its only the ones that don't have the `media_url_https` causing the issue and not being displayed either!

Comment: @James, do I need to start the `if (item.entities.media)` inside my `$.each() ` condition?

Comment: @DavidHope Yep, only add an image to the html string `if (item.entities.media && item.entities.media.length && item.entities.media[0].media_url_https)`

Comment: so the clue is `item.entities.media is undefined`.... tells you need to check that property. Your console is vital to debugging and will give you such clues

Comment: @James, that did it mate. Thank you very much. if you want you can answer that and I'll select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all of your `items` have an `entities` property but only some of those `entities` have a `media` property, you should check for the existence of that `media` property and all of its sub-properties down to `media_url_https` before using it to build your html string, ie:

```
if (item.entities.media 
  && item.entities.media.length 
  && item.entities.media[0].media_url_https) {
  // code to add image to html string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand about your question and your comments: you are wondering *Given an object that may or may not have certain properties, how can I account for properties that don't exist?* specifically with your img.

As mentioned in the comments, you can write a conditional for some of the properties to fill in values if they don't exist and it *should* still iterate over all the data.

One method I like to suggest for default values is a utilization of JavaScript's [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) functionality, allowing us to treat regular variables *kinda* like booleans.

```
var products = '<div id="'+item.id_str+'" class="items">'+
            '<p class="names">'+item.created_at+'</p>'+
            '<p class="names">'+item.text+'</p>'+
            '<img src="'+(item.entities.media[0].media_url_https || "./img/default_img.png")+'" width="100%">'+
            '</div>';
```

In this snippet of code I utilize the fact that each value in JavaScript has a "truthy" or "falsy" value to it, and using a boolean or operator I can actually coalesce a "falsy" value into a "truthy" default one.

In plain english the line I changed would be along the lines of "Use `item.entities.media[0].media_url_https` if its value exists and isn't empty, otherwise use `"./img/default_img.png"`.

And if it wasn't clear you can change the `"./img/default_img.png"` to anything you want, another variable, a different string constant, etc.

I like to use truthy evaluations like this because it helps to keep your code fairly clean and it really saves space and the amount of data needed to be sent to the browser (even if it's a negligible amount).

Answer (score 0):

Based on James comment, This worked like a charm.

```
    var poutput = $('.listHolder');

    $.ajax({
    url: 'PAGE.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data){




        $.each(data, function(pi,item){ 


        if (item.entities.media && item.entities.media.length && item.entities.media[0].media_url_https){



        var media = '<img src="'+item.entities.media[0].media_url_https+'" width="100%">';
        var products = '<div id="'+item.id_str+'" class="items">'+
                       '<p class="names">'+item.text+'</p>'+
                        media+
                        '</div>';

        }else{



        var products = '<div id="'+item.id_str+'" class="items">'+
                       '<p class="names">'+item.text+'</p>'+
                        '</div>';
        }






               console.log(products);

                poutput.append(products);




});


},

        error: function(){
            //alert('There was an error loading the data.');
        }


});
```